# How to show a polynomial generates an ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra

let $ ∶= ⟨, ⟩ ∩ ℚ[]$ be the elimination ideal.

When $ =  − 1$ and $ = ^2 + ^2 − 4$, prove that $Res(, ; )$ generates $J$.

So I have computed the resultant and gotten a polynomial: $-4(-4y^2+1)$, how do I show this generates J?

Comment: Some thoughts: note that $\mathbb{Q}[y]$ is principal and 

$$
p := -4(-4y^2+1) = 16y^2-4 = (4y)^2-4 = (4y-2)(4y+2).
$$

Since $J = (h)$ for some $h \in \mathbb{Q}[y]$, if $p \in (h)$ then we have $h \mid p$.  Thus either $h = p$, or $h$ is one of the irreducible factors displayed above, which - modulo units - are $y\pm 1/2$.  So one option could be to try and show that that the latter cannot generate $J$, but $p \in (h)$, hence the only option is to have $p = h$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4056813/prove-resf-gx-generates-j-given-2-polynomials

Comment: I get a different answer for the resultant. Do you know how to compute a Gröbner basis for $(f,g)$? If so, you can easily use that to prove that $J$ is generated by the resultant.